# Angular: how to resize Search Filter Pipe

Tags: angular

I created a Search Filter Pipe with ng2-search-filter; the problem is that the input text bar has the same length as the table, but I would like it to be smaller.

Here's the picture:

[image: Search Filter Pipe]

I tried using the word size but it didn't work.
How can I decrease the size? thank you all

Code:

app.module.ts

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  filterTerm: string;

  userRecords = [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Leanne Graham",
      "username": "Bret",
      "email": "Sincere@april.biz"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ervin Howell",
      "username": "Antonette",
      "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv"
    },
    ....
   ]
}
```

app.component.html

```js
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="filterTerm">
  </div>

  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Username</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of userRecords | filter:filterTerm">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a style class for this input

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="filterTerm">
```

Then set a width to .search-input class

```
.search-input{
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it works. I thank you so much.
It's okay either as you said (in CSS) or by using specific commands in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Can easily add col-6, col-4 depending on what you want to achieve

```
<div class="form-group col-12 col-lg-5 col-md-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="filterTerm">
  </div>
```

Comment: @elfuso wrap it with <div class="row"></div> I hope it will work

Comment: perfect, it works. For those who want to use bootstrap this is the best solution. I thank you so much